# Cannot login on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, login

I installed Nvidia drivers and now I cannot log on to my computer whatsoever, not even as guest. The login screen appears to be zoomed in more than when it was working. I tried purging nvidia and reinstalling but it was in no help at all.

After trying to configure the problem using the forums on my own, when i go to login the screen turns black and white text that appears really fast and disappears saying "Failed to locate..." or something.

I'm a novice at ubuntu and just wondering if anyone has expirienced similar problems and found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you share the commands and order of what you tried?

I had a similar issue and have heard this referred to as the login loop issue.

**Open command to investigate/fix errors on login using:**

When you get to the login screen (that is zoomed in and won't let you login).

- Hit ctrl+alt+f1
- Login using your credentials you would use at login
  screen
- Type `cat .xsession-errors`
- Research errors

**Solutions that worked for me:**

*Replace nvidia-current driver with xserver-xorg-video-nouveau driver:*

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`
- `sudo reboot`

*Disable secure boot in bios:*

- Restart pc and enter your bios setup (http://www.pcworld.com/article/241032/how_to_enter_your_pcs_bios.html)
- Find the option "Secure Boot", most likely in "BOOT" options
- Disable Secure Boot

Answer (score 0):

MarCrazyness is correct on his second solution to disable Secure Boot.  A recent kernel update (linux-image-4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1) indicates that systems with an EFI BIOS and Secure Boot enabled will enforce the use of signed 3rd-party drivers.

Reference: [LP: #1566221](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566221)

'3rd-party drivers' includes the nvidia binary driver.

Previous updates to the Linux kernel would only log that it was 'tainted' when using 3rd-party drivers, but the drivers would still load.  With the current update, the driver will no longer load.

Due to the configuration of the X server, this will set your display manager to a low-resolution mode and prevent the full desktop environment from loading when you log in.  When you log in, it will throw an error and immediately log you out.

The easiest solution is to disable the Secure Boot option in your BIOS.